# Error near: ")" in SqliteConnection Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, sqlite

I've been working how to fix this for so many hours but I can't find any solutions. I'm getting that error whenever I'm trying to insert new record.

Here's my code.

// SqliteConnection declaration

```
public SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "myDB.db3"));
```

//My class table

```
[Table("BELToDoTask_TB")]
public class BELToDoTask_TB
{
    [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement,Column("_id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string TaskName { get; set; }
}
```

// and lastly, my table creation and inserting of data

```
// START Get Connection 
    DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
    // END Get...##########

    // START Create new task 
    public string CreateTask(string TaskName)
    {
        try
        {
            dbcon.con.CreateTable<BELToDoTask_TB>();

            BELToDoTask_TB beltodotask = new BELToDoTask_TB();

            beltodotask.TaskName = TaskName;

            dbcon.con.Insert(TaskName);

            return "Task has been successfully created...";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error: " + e.Message;
        }
    }
// END Create...########
```

Please help!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is a compiler error, or a runtime error?  What is the exact text of the error?

Comment: Where are you creating the SQL statement? Looks like a SQL statement error. Also, are you just saving the passed in string parameter on purpose? You seem to set it to the `beltodotask.TaskName`, but then you don't do anything with that object.